# Vue.js - using v-el inside v-for doesnt work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to animate certain divs inside v-for loop on click event. For that i need to have dom/jquery elements to work on. Of course i dont want to animate all elements at once, just these specific ones i click.

I wanted to use v-el to achive this, but it doesnt work, $els object doesnt return anything. This is what i tried:

```
<li v-for="element in elements" v-el="li">

    <span v-el="span">lorem</span>
    <span v-el="span2"> ipsium {{element.content}}</span>

</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w1cd96ux/

Answer (score 2):

`v-el` doesn't work on or within a `v-for`. If each `<li>` is a component you can use `v-ref` though then you'd have access to each `span` through `v-el` (which is deprecated in the next version of Vue).

I'd probably just take this approach, if I'm understanding correctly:

```
<li v-for="item in items" @click="animate">
  <span>...</span>
  <span>...</span>
</li>
```

Then in your methods you can do:

```
methods: {
  animate(event) {
    const li = event.currentTarget
    const spans = li.querySelectorAll('span')
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What if my method had its own parameter? How i use my paramater along with this default "event" parameter?

Comment: You'd have to do like `@click="animate($event, param)"` then in your method `animate(event, param)`.

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

1. Correct way to define `v-el` as per latest version is `v-el:span`. check this link https://vuejs.org/api/#v-el
2. your `this` inside `ready` method points to top level `div` so if you put the `v-el` at top level and try to print in ready function, it will print.

check this jsfiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/oyomyosw/
```

Comment: span and span2 still return undefined